# D3: How to add multiple elements to patterns through data binding

Tags: d3.js, dom, data-binding

I am trying to make patterns using data binding. Each pattern should contain a rect and an image as siblings. I am able to append image in rect, but unable to append as sibling. How can I achieve this? Also, I am using window resize event handler, so I need to pass in x, y coordinates for the image as well.

Code:

```
    // Add Definition to SVG
    const defs = svg.selectAll("defs").data([true]).join("defs");

    const pattern = defs.selectAll(".pattern-image").data(data);

    // Add Elements to pattern

    pattern.join((enter) =>
      enter
        .append("pattern")
        .attr("id", (d, i) => "p" + i)
        .attr("class", "pattern-image")
        .attr("height", "1")
        .attr("width", "1")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "pattern-rect")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .append("image")
        .attr("class", "flag-image")
        .append("image")
        .attr("class", "flag-image")
        .attr("x", (d) => xScale(xValue(d)) - yScale.bandwidth() - 2)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("width", yScale.bandwidth())
        .attr(
          "xlink:href",
          (d) => "https://www.countryflags.io/" + d.Code + "/flat/64.png"
        )
        .attr("clip-path", (d, i) => "url(#cp" + i + ")")
    );
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the relevant code you have. If you have something like: `var parent = selectAll().data().enter("parentElement")`, you can append sibling children for each parent with `parent.append("element1"); parent.append("element2")`, the bound data is passed to the children and each parent will have two sibling elements in it. But seeing what you have would help in seeing if I'm understanding the question right.

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look.